# Xcode 9 Beta 2 libxml error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, libxml2

When I build my project with beta 1 it works just fine, but in beta 2 it does not work. In this build I get all sort of errors with libxml I think. For example:

```
* tree.h:81:3: Unsupported: typedef changes linkage of anonymous type, but linkage was
already computed

* tree.h:346:8: Redefinition of '_xmlElement'
```

I think this is because somehow libxml is include twice in my project or something. If I change all the `#include/imports` with the `@import xml2` statements it compiles again. The include are guarded by defines.

I want to know if this is the correct solution and why this is needed or is this a bug?

To reproduce problem:

I'm using a wrapper around libxml so I can use objc. When I strip all code the problem can be reproduced with these files/classes:

```
// DDXMLNode.h
#import <libxml/tree.h>

//@import xml2.tree;
@import Foundation;
@import ObjectiveC.runtime;

@interface DDXMLNode : NSObject<NSCopying>

@end

// DDXMLNode.m
#import "DDXMLNode.h"

@implementation DDXMLNode
@end
```

I added libxml2 through build phases and just add libxml2.tbd.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Am getting this exact problem.  It doesn't happen in Xcode 9 beta 1.  It is new in beta 2.  I was hoping that it would get fixed in beta 3.  However, I'll try your work around.

Comment: I can confirm that using @import xml2 is a valid workaround

Comment: oh I just saw @Calimari328 comment. Will wait for beta 3 then. Is xml2 import the same as libxml include? Since xml2 is build on top of libxml

Comment: @ScareCrow I think xml2 is the name of the module for all the libxml files.  I wonder how many others are effected by this change.  The only other one I can think of is sqlite.  I can't remember which wwdc video I heard it from.

Comment: Looks like the issue was fixed in beta 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calimari328 said in the comments this is fixed in xCode beta 3.